# Refresh before a TClientDataSet Insert or Append

Tags: delphi, refresh, tclientdataset, dbgrid

I have in my application Masters and Details ClientDataSets,I used a TDBGrid and linked with Detail.

When I do an Insert or Append without refresh, the records from DBGrid disappear, but the records of the ClientDataSet continue.

Is this right or is there another way to do this without using a resync?

Comment: How is the master detail relationship implemented, nested datasets or traditional MasterFields/DataSource?
What does "records of the ClientDataSet continue" actually mean?
Are you doing the Insert/Append on the master or detail dataset?

Comment: @LachlanG I mean that disappeared the grid's records when I do an Insert/Append, but when I checked the records of detail dataset showed that had 2 records.

Comment: Which of these methods are you using to create your master/detail clientdatasets?
MasterSource and MasterFields properties
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Making_the_Table_a_Detail_of_Another_Dataset
or Nested DataSets
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Using_Nested_Detail_Tables

Comment: Are you doing the Insert on the master or detail clientdataset?

Comment: @LachlanG The insert is on detail clientdataset.
I'm using the second link, Nested DataSets